# How to execute script on local machine from server with ssh2

Tags: node.js, ssh, ssh2

I want to execute a script that is in a folder in a server machine, over my local machine.
I use ssh2 to create the connection between server and local machine.

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");


function connectIn(req, res) {
    console.log('ENTRANDO EN CONNECTION SSH', req.body);
  const repoFile = "cd C:\repoScripts\shutdown.bat";
    const conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Client :: ready');
        conn.exec('type /repoScript/shutdown.bat', (err, stream) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          stream.on('close', (code, signal) => {
            console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
            conn.end();
          }).on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
          }).stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
          });
        });
      }).connect({
        host: '192.168.1.130',
        port: 22,
        username: 'ddaud',
        password: 'Mraixa0319T'
      });


}

module.exports = { connectIn }
```

the connect data are the server and i can connect and make a dir or whatever in the server, but i can not find and execute the script over my local machine.

Someone has some idea?
thanks

Comment: Is `ssh` in command line in a shell works over your local machine?

Comment: yes, in my local machine i can launch this function from postman, and works to handle the connect{server}